# Autogenerating Hibernate annotations from XSD

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jaxb, xsd

I have been using `jaxb` to autogenerate Java classes from XSD files.  I am seeking a list the various ways that I can also autogenerate the Hibernate annotations for persisting the data from the classes into a relational database.  If the Hibernate annotations are autogenerated, then creating the database structures should be automatic using `hbm2ddl`.

I need to import XML data into a relational structure which can then be used by other apps.  I have been experimenting with [hyperjaxb](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/HJ3/Home), and I may stick with it, but there seem to be a lot of picky settings, for example its default settings can result in cripplingly verbose SQL statements.  See [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707619/hibernate-jpa-derby-select-statement-has-too-many-items-in-group-by-order-b) and [this other posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597201/customizing-hibernate-properties-in-hyperjaxb).

I have read about [Dali](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/) and [EclipseLink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/), but it seems that neither of these other tools use Hibernate.  I would like to stick with Hibernate.  What are the options?

Comment: I'd actually LOVE to hear that there's an analog for Hyperjaxb.

Comment: There are a lot of analogs for `hyperjaxb`.  They use other inputs like `uml` which are themselves easy to generate.  I am just wondering what people's experience is.  I would like to use well documented libraries that are supported by teams.  Picking through poor documentation is time consuming.

Comment: Exactly, they use *other* inputs. By "analog" I mean a schema-driven tool which would generate JPA-enabled classes from an XML Schema.

Comment: If they are well documented with a development team and users who answer questions with clear working examples, they could save a lot of time.  There are tools that generate the various elements of JPA enabled classes from formats that are analogous to xsd.